# How to convert american date format to GB date format?

Tags: t-sql

I have the following script which returns a date formatted to US, id like to convert it to GB date format and it should only return the date part.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1       
select  case @dateType 
WHEN 'Daily' then i.overridedate 
WHEN 'Weekly' then dateadd(day,-1*datepart(weekday,i.overridedate)+1,i.overridedate) 
WHEN 'Monthly' THEN DATEADD(day, -1*DATEpart(day,i.overridedate)+1, i.overridedate) 
WHEN 'Quarterly' THEN dateadd(mm,-3,DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq,0,i.overridedate )+1, 0))  END as 'date'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the convert function for this:

`SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 105)`

For GB, the correct styling would be 103, based on this table: http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Where 105 is a styling.  I found this trick at this blog:  http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: For GB it should be 103 judging by msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.

Comment: @SINTER Yes, thanks for that, I've incorporated your comment into my answer.  Fortunately Italy and GB use the same dd-mm-yyyy convention, so the results should have been the same but better to specify exactly what is wanted.